# Scrapy does not scrape 'next page' data (it scraped only the first page)

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm not getting the data from the next pages (first page is fine.)

I have tried a couple methods as shown below (In the first I did robots_obey = false; download_delay = 8;  and changed the user agent. In the second, again tried changing user agent based on that of the website, then tried overriding request headers with that user agent, each time commenting previous one out, and robots_obey was again set to false. Platform is Python v 3.6. First method was tried on windows 10 and Ubuntu 18. Second, was tried only on windows.)

Method 1

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class ScrapeDfo2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrape-dfo2'
    allowed_domains = ['canada.ca']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.canada.ca/en/news/advanced-news-search/news-results.html?typ=newsreleases&dprtmnt=fisheriesoceans&start=&end=']

    def parse(self, response):
        quotes = response.xpath('//*[@class="h5"]')
        for quote in quotes:
            title = quote.xpath('.//a/text()').extract_first()
            link = quote.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()

            yield {'Title': title,
                   'Link': link}

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[@rel="next"]/@href').extract()
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url))
```

Method 2

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class ScrapeDfo2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrape-dfo2'
    allowed_domains = ['canada.ca']
    # start_urls = ['https://www.canada.ca/en/news/advanced-news-search/news-results.html?typ=newsreleases&dprtmnt=fisheriesoceans&start=&end=']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.canada.ca/en/news/advanced-news-search/news-results.html?typ=newsreleases&dprtmnt=fisheriesoceans&start=&end=', callback=self.parse, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'})

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.xpath('//*[@class="h5"]'):
            yield{
                'Title': quote.xpath('.//a/text()').get(),
                'Link': quote.xpath('.//a/@href').get(),
                'User-Agent': response.request.headers['User-Agent']}

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[@rel="next"]/@href').extract()
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url), headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'})
    # def parse(self, response):
    #     quotes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hove it may help you.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class CanadaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'canada'
    allowed_domains = ['canada.ca']
    start_urls = ['https://www.canada.ca/en/news/advanced-news-search/news-results.html?start=&typ=newsreleases&end=&idx=0&dprtmnt=fisheriesoceans']

    page_count = 0

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(self.page_count, 690, 10):
            yield scrapy.Request('https://www.canada.ca/en/news/advanced-news-search/news-results.html?start=&typ=newsreleases&end=&idx=%d&dprtmnt=fisheriesoceans'%i, callback=self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):

        quotes = response.xpath('//*[@class="h5"]')
        for quote in quotes:
            title = quote.xpath('.//a/text()').extract_first()
            link = quote.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()

            yield {'Title': title,
               'Link': link}
```

## some output here

```
{'Title': 'Canadian small businesses create innovative solutions to help reduce plastic pollution in our oceans', 'Link': 'https://www.canada.ca/en/fisheries-oceans/news/2020/06/canadian-small-businesses-create-innovative-solutions-to-help-reduce-plastic-pollution-in-our-oceans.html'}
2020-06-15 05:57:33 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.canada.ca/en/news/advanced-news-search/news-results.html?start=&typ=newsreleases&end=&idx=0&dprtmnt=fisheriesoceans>
{'Title': 'Government of Canada takes the fight against illegal fishing to outer space', 'Link': 'https://www.canada.ca/en/fisheries-oceans/news/2020/06/government-of-canada-takes-the-fight-against-illegal-fishing-to-outer-space.html'}
2020-06-15 05:57:33 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.canada.ca/en/news/advanced-news-search/news-results.html?start=&typ=newsreleases&end=&idx=0&dprtmnt=fisheriesoceans>
{'Title': 'Closed areas for shellfish harvesting on the North Shore', 'Link': 'https://www.canada.ca/en/fisheries-oceans/news/2020/06/closed-areas-for-shellfish-harvesting-on-the-north-shore.html'}
```

Comment: Hello Samsul, this is very helpful. In particular as it allows you to control how many pages you want. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question below (didn't try the above, yet)

Answer below is for method 2. One key part of it is to make sure, towards the end, that the line that handles pagination is outside the for loop.

```
import scrapy

class ScrapeDfo2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrape-dfo2'
    allowed_domains = ['www.canada.ca']
    # start_urls = ['https://www.canada.ca/en/news/advanced-news-search/news-results.html?typ=newsreleases&dprtmnt=fisheriesoceans&start=&end=']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.canada.ca/en/news/advanced-news-search/news-results.html?typ=newsreleases&dprtmnt=fisheriesoceans&start=&end=', callback=self.parse, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'})

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.xpath('//*[@class="h5"]'):
            yield{
                'Title': quote.xpath('.//a/text()').get(),
                'Link': quote.xpath('.//a/@href').get(),
                'User-Agent': response.request.headers['User-Agent']}

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[@rel="next"]/@href').get()

        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(next_page_url), headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'})
```